# Text for Button 2 is Displaying in Text Box for Button 1 - VS Express 2013 -

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Not sure how to fix or what I am doing wrong? Please help....

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ariesText.Click
    Me.displayText.Text += "Aries'The Ram' March 21 - April 19 Aries people are creative, adaptive, and insightful.  They can also be strong-willed and spontaneous (sometimes to a fault)."

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles taurusText.Click
    Me.displayText.Text += "Taurus 'The Bull' April 20 - May 20 Taurus zodiac signs and meanings, like the animal that represents them, is all about strength, stamina and will. Stubborn by nature, the Taurus will stand his/her ground to the bitter end (sometimes even irrationally so)."

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove `+` sign *(it will append the text, in your case you have to overwrite it)*

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ariesText.Click

        Me.displayText.Text = "Aries'The Ram' March 21 - April 19 Aries people are creative, adaptive, and insightful.  They can also be strong-willed and spontaneous (sometimes to a fault)."

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles taurusText.Click

        Me.displayText.Text = "Taurus 'The Bull' April 20 - May 20 Taurus zodiac signs and meanings, like the animal that represents them, is all about strength, stamina and will. Stubborn by nature, the Taurus will stand his/her ground to the bitter end (sometimes even irrationally so)."

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am creating 12 Buttons and 12 Text Boxes for an Astrology webform. So The initial question is What Sign Are You? and then I am attempting to put all of the Zodiac Signs with a button for each one and when they choose their sign, the Text should display the Traits I have entered in the Text field. Hope that makes sense....

Comment: If using 12 textboxes, why setting vales to `Me.displayText`?